# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on UIView animated

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, swift3

Good afternoon,

I try to implement a UITapGestureRecognizer on a UIView.

I created the UITapGestureRecognizer and assign to my UIView like this.

```
let gestureGeneral = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.toConfigurationGeneral(_:)))
self.mode_view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureGeneral)
```

This is my method toConfigurationGeneral :

```
func toConfigurationGeneral(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfigurationGeneralViewController") as! ConfigurationGeneralViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: false)
}
```

This code is working great but when I add an animation on this UIView, my method is not called. This is my animation :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction, .allowAnimatedContent], animations: {
        self.mode_view.alpha = 0
} , completion: nil)
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

When the `alpha` of your view is set to `0`, all `GestureRecognizer` are unable.

You could add a **new subview** with a clear background color with the same frame of your `mode_view` and the same `mode_view`. 
And add to it the `GestureRecognizer`.
When your `mode_view` will be hide, the **new subview** will call the method.

You could also only add the gesture on this *clear backgrounded new subview*

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to use GestureRecognizer you need userInteractionEnabled set to true for your view
Please confirm your
mode_view.userInteractionEnabled = true